# Octavo environment stanza break spacing

Tags: spacing, templates, paragraphs, verse, octavo

In the `octavo` document-class, there is (as in many others) a `verse` environment for the setting of poetry; however, breaking stanzas appears to be unimplemented: there's no difference in vertical spacing between line-breaks and paragraph-breaks. I can fix this with a hack: using `\medskip` between each stanza; but is there a way to enable proper automatic paragraph spacing in `octavo`'s `verse` environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`octavo`'s definition of the `verse` environment is identical to that of `article`; however (and possibly due to changes in the underlying `list` environment), the length `\parsep` is set to 0pt. You may add a positive `\parsep` to the definition of `verse`.

```
\documentclass{octavo}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{verse}
    {\let\\=\@centercr
    \list{}{\itemsep \z@
    \parsep 4pt plus 2pt minus 1pt% NEW
    \itemindent -1.5em%
    \listparindent\itemindent
    \rightmargin \leftmargin
    \advance\leftmargin 1.5em}%
    \item[]}
    {\endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
A\\
B

C\\
D
\end{verse}

\end{document}​
```